# fourier transform rotation property

Tags: proof-writing, rotations, fourier-transform

I need to show that
$$\widehat{f(Ax)}(\xi)=\hat{f}(A\xi)$$
where $A$ is a orthogonal $d\times d$ matrix (thus $A^{-1}=A^T$). The definition of the Fourier transform is:
$$\hat{f}(\xi):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot \xi}dx$$

Now I think this can be done with a change of variables $y=Ax$ and since we know that $A$ is orthogonal we have $det(A)=1$. And I also know from the hints to use $A^{-1}y\cdot \xi=y\cdot A\xi$.

But my math is a bit rusty and I am not sure how to express $\widehat{f(Ax)}(\xi)$ in integral form.
It seems to simple just to say
$$\widehat{f(Ax)}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(Ax)e^{-2\pi iAx\cdot \xi}Adx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(y)e^{-2\pi iy\cdot \xi}AA^{-1}dy$$

Can someone help me with the first steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the definition of the Fourier transform, use the change of variable 
$z = Ax$; $dz = |\det A| dx = dx$ then in the shoulder of the exponential use \begin{equation*}
x\cdot\xi = A^Tz\cdot \xi= z\cdot A\xi.
\end{equation*}
We want to compute the transform of the function $g(x) = f(Ax)$, so using the above we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\widehat g(\xi)
& = & 
\int_{\mathbb R^d}g(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\; dx
\\
& = & 
\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(Ax)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \xi}\; dx
\\
& = & 
\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(z)e^{-2\pi i A^Tz\cdot \xi}\; dz
\\
& = & 
\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(z)e^{-2\pi i z\cdot A\xi}\; dz
\\
& = & 
\widehat f(A\xi)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Oh sure, I should have used the definition correctly. Now it's pretty obvious. Thanks very much!

Comment: @BindersFull Nice answer! Why exactly is `dz = |det A| dx` ?

Comment: @Ethunxxx Thats the Jacobian determinant for the change of variable $z = Ax$.

Comment: True! Thanks a lot!